# IIS shared config on network drive - if network is down for a bit, IIS doesn't recover

Tags: iis, shared-config

We have several servers using shared IIS config stored on a network storage. After access to that storage is down for a few seconds (and then comes back), IIS isn't working until you do iisreset.

The problem seems to be that the local app pool config files become corrupted. To be more precise, the error given out is "Configuration file is not well-formed XML", and if you go to the app pool config, you see that instead of an actual config, it contains the following:

Now, trying to solve this we've come across the "Offline Files" feature and tried it for the shared applicationHost.config, but it wouldn't sync (saying other process is using the file, which is strange - I can easily change and save it). 
The shared path starts with an IP (like \1.2.3.4...) - perhaps that's the issue (can't figure why it would be, just out of ideas at this point)?

Basically, I have two questions:
1) If the shared config is unavailable for a bit, how to make IIS recover and not be left with corrupt files till iisreset?
2) Any other idea to prevent this situation altogether.

Comment: Something you should check with Microsoft technical support team.

Answer (score 0):

We did manage to get offline files to work - the problem was the network drive is over Samba, and had to have oplocks on - otherwise was telling it can't sync because file is used by another process.
Now, the IIS does recover - actually, doesn't go down with the drive. However, since our websites are also on that drive, they are not available during network outage (which is predictable), the last strange thing is that it takes IIS about 1 minute to "feel" them again after the drive is back online.